# Oracle Applications: What is the flag based on which system picks multiple lines selected in OM:Shipping Transaction Form?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-apps

On Oracle Apps Order Management Shipping Transaction Form, multiple lines can be selection to launch pick release or for other actions on the Lines/LPNs tab.

I want to write a form personalization on the selected lines.

Is there a flag that is checked for the lines selected? What is the criteria based on which Oracle Applications picks multiple lines selected at Shipping Transaction Form?

I have attached an image showing selected lines. These lines are in blue.

[Shipping Transaction Form showing selected lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSRA0.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried clicking on help>diagnostics? I would expect for you to see the form attributes there associated with this selection.

Comment: I have. I did check Help>Diagnostics. Also checked this form's WSHFSTRX.fmb file. I even took a trace of these form actions but couldn't find anything substantial.